# Replaced routers, added Pi-Hole as DNS - single machine gets DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN for certains sites

Tags: networking, windows-10, router, dns, pihole

Bit of info on the network.

1. Ziggo ConnectBox (modem/router) in bridge mode ([this horror](https://www.ziggo.nl/klantenservice/wifi/modem/connect-box/))
2. Linksys WRT32X ([this one](https://www.linksys.com/us/p/P-WRT32X/) - 192.168.1.1) - primary DHCP, uses Pi-Hole for DNS (192.168.1.x static)
3. Linksys WRT32X (192.168.2.1, DHCP enabled, uses 192.168.1.1 as DNS)

Router 1 is downstairs, router 2 is upstairs.

---

So, that is, since today, the setup.

The problem, a single computer on router 2 has the issue that it gets "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN" on certain domains. Seems to be specific to Facebook domains as it affects Facebook and Instragram. (Don't judge, not my pc...)

About the PC:

- standard Windows 1803 protection shizzle
- pretty much only things installed are browser (Chrome) and games via Steam/Origin

---

I've already tried a bunch of things:

- reset all flags via `chrome://flags`
- dump all cache/cookies in Chrome
- Change adapter DNS servers to Google's servers (also to 1.1.1.1 & 1.0.0.1 which the Pi-hole uses)
- `ipconfig /flushdns` (also as admin)
- `netsh winsock reset`
- Since Win10 1803 cannot reset DNS Service via `services.msc` (not even using [`psexec` tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec))
- Uninstall network adapter, reboot and re-install
- Other browsers on PC (IE11 & Edge)
- [answer by Dennis](https://superuser.com/a/1406568/209794) below

(above list pretty much only solutions on first few google pages when searching variations of the issue)

But still... the missus cannot visit her FB/Insta 'whatevs' on that pc.

I'm hoping any of you got any idea of new things to try.

---

P.s. - asking here instead of network SE as it's a Windows pc (and no other computer/phone on the network has issues)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more commands to completely reset all things TCP/IP and DNS:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults: `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults: `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Flush DNS resolver cache: `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases: `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table: `route /f`

After that you should reboot the machine.

Comment: Hi thanks, didn't know about those, thanks. But alas, did not work :|